# Google Doc - applying headers to single line only - after pasting as plain text

Tags: google-docs, formatting, text-formatting

The issue: https://youtu.be/OXS3wTR7YJw

1. Make notes in "Notes" (better for offline)
2. Paste into Google Doc
3. Apply a header
4. Sh!t the whole thing is formatted now

---

Related but not the same: [Create documents with plain text formatting in Google Docs](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/18293/create-documents-with-plain-text-formatting-in-google-docs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that Notes uses carriage return (`\r`) as new lines whereas Google Docs and Windows use a combination of carriage return and new line (`\r\n`)

The following code in Apps Scripts will break the paragraphs apart:

```
function replaceSoftReturns() {
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var body = doc.getBody();
  var newParagraphs = body.getText().split("\r");
  body.clear();
  newParagraphs.forEach(function(txt){body.appendParagraph(txt)})
}
```

Comment: Something weird... Not sure if that is just me... Seems like it is fixed by default now? Do you mind checking on your end?

Comment: It's the same on my end. Maybe there was an update to Apple Notes and it now uses `\r\n`